# I want to be able to pipe stdout into gist on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: pipe, stdout, paste, ubuntu-14.04

I'm unable to find any details on how to do this.  I've been using the hastebin *haste gem and when that was failing to work I was using pastebinit.  But gist has significantly more lax character limits I would like to be able to send stdout to a gist when possible.

I hear theres a package somewhere called *wgetpaste but I have no idea how to use or install these. If someone could tell me where to start or how to do this it would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst waiting a response I discovered that I can simply run.

```
apt-get install gist
```

When I want to output something to gist I simply use it like this.

```
cat /home/user/somefile.txt |gist-paste
```

It returns this.

```
user@one:~$ cat somefile.txt |gist-paste
https://gist.github.com/f20e4eee087955be59a9
user@one:~$
```

Comment: Just as a note, available via package management in Ubuntu since 14.04 - trusty -, but it can manually be installed - more information on the [gist cli client github page](https://github.com/defunkt/gist).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<generate input> | xargs -I {} gist <options> {}
```

Comment: is gist installed with git?